# Import SecureCrt XML session file into MobaXterm not working

Tags: session, mobaxterm, secure-crt

I have recently started working at a new job,and unfortunately i can't install SecureCrt at the moment from various reasons.

A colleague of mine is working with Scrt, so we decided he'll export his sessions into XML and i'll import them in MobaXterm.

I am trying to import the XML file into the MobaXterm but nothing happens:

1. Open sessions tab
2. Right click in saved user sessions pane
3. Select "Import SCRT sessions" from drop-down

Comment: Paste the log from MobaXterm:

 1. Help
 2. View MobaXterm log file

Answer (score 0):

Apparently MobaXterm imports SecureCRT sessions only if there is a SecureCRT also installed on the same Windows machine.

I found a workaround to (somehow) import sessions from SecureCRT (Version 7.1.1 (build 264)) into MobaXterm but this probably will not help you if even temporarily able to install SecureCRT:

1) on the source machine where SecureCRT is running zip the complete install directory of VanDyke (for me it was: "C:\Program Files (x86)\VanDyke Software") and appdata directory (for me it was: "C:\Users\id084265\AppData\Roaming\VanDyke"). The sessions are actually stored in the latter directory.
2) Copy the zipped files onto target machine
3) Unzip and extract them as Administrator into the same locations on the target machine (for me "C:\Program Files (x86)\" and ""C:\Users\id084265\AppData\Roaming\" respectively)
4) Run at least ones the securecCRT on the target machine. It will ask where the appdata should be stored and (probably) suggest the where you stored the copied ones. If not change it to that directory so that you get your sessions back into SecureCRT.
5) now you can import the SCRT sessions into MobaXterm as yourself explained above.